# Bash function call error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need some help in Bash function while passing arguments. I need to pass arguments into SQL query in Bash but I am getting error message.

```
#!/bin/bash --

whw='mysql -uroot -proot -habczx.net'


function foo() {
  for v in "$@"; do
    eval "$v";            # line 9
    echo "${v}";
  done

  ${whw} -e"select id, idCfg, idMfg, $DATE from tblMfg"
}

foo DATE="curdate()"
```

Below is the error message I get:

```
$ sh test4.sh
test4.sh: eval: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test4.sh: eval: line 9: `DATE=curdate()'
test4.sh: line 9: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to     abort as Posix requires
DATE=curdate()
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from tblMfg limit 4' at line 1
```

==

If I change in function call to below I do not get any error message:

```
foo DATE="2014-12-21"
```

==

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the evaluated expression. You can see that by typing it:

```
$ DATE=bla()
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If you put it in quotes, it will work:

```
$ DATE="bla()"
```

In order to pass the quotes to the eval, they need to be protected from evaluation at callsite:

```
foo 'DATE="curdate()"'
```

should do the trick.

BTW: this is rather dangerous to eval a string, especially if the arguments are from untrusted users, one could use `foo "rm -rf /"` :)

I am not sure why you need the eval, instead of $DATE you could also use $1 and then

```
${whw} -e"SELECT ... $1...."
foo "curdate()"
```

Comment: Do you mean putting double quotation in function call? If you look at it I am putting double quotation but still getting error: foo DATE="curdate()"

Comment: Yes, but you need to escape them, the caller would strip them off: `foo 'DATE="curdate()"'` or `foo DATE=\"curdate()\"` or similiar. If you put your echo before the eval you can actually better see what is actually parsed.

Comment: The query runs this time. But I am getting error message: test4.sh: eval: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
test4.sh: line 10: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires

Comment: Hm, it works for me. When I move the echo up and replace "mysql" with echo it prints with no error: `$ ./b.sh
DATE="curdate()"
-uroot -proot -habczx.net -eselect id, idCfg, idMfg, curdate() from tblMfg`

Comment: oh, yes use the '' variant, the \" needs two quotes: `DATE="\"currdate()\""`